# Running Isolated Tests Without Relying on Terminal? IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea, terminal, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

I understand that I should use the [sure-fire](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/) plugin for unit tests, and [failsafe](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) for integration. I can run unit tests with `mvn test` and integration tests with `mvn verify` but this annoys me for 2 reasons:

1. I'd prefer to be able to select any test class (or method in that class) and run it individually by a simple click, rather than typing it into terminal every time.
2. The terminal returns the test results in ugly black/white paragraphs, requiring me to sift through them. I'd much prefer to have the results returned in a visually organized manner, similar to if I right-clicked on the test class in IntelliJ and click 'RunDemoTest`. This produces:

[image]

I find the error results much easier to sift through, for example it shows red/green `@Test` results on the left, and on the right it cleanly organizes the error into

> Expected : 3
>
> Actual :1

I'm sure there are advantages to using terminal for automated test runs later into production, but during development I don't find the terminal conducive to my tinkering.

How do I benefit from IntelliJ's visual feedback of test results, while simultaneously ensuring unit & integration tests are run separately, and preserving my freedom to pick and choose which *test classes and test methods* I can run at any time?

I'm assuming I can't have my cake and eat it too. Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the IntelliJ view "Maven Projects" you can very easy toggle on/off the exection of maven integrated tests.
[image]

Via "Run/Debug Configurations" you can create test executions that match your reqirement for a comfortable UI.

[image]

After these steps, there is a new entry in the drop down list "Run/Debug configurations". When you start the new JUnit Test configuration, the defined tests are executed and the results are presented **exactly in the same manner** as the screenshot in your question.

The options in my second screenshot allow a very flexible definition of the scope. You don't have go to every java file and click on the green arrows in the editor view.

[image]

This configuration isn't related to any maven configuration, and you can use them at any time in your coding process.

Comment: Sorry Jim, but I have no idea how your second screenshot shows how to create a comfortable UI, namely one that conforms to the red/green requirements I mentioned above. Your screenshot highlights where to change the **kind** of test, package, and where to search, along with working directory. I don't understand how this relates to constructing a UI. I've +1 you for giving feedback but can't award a checkmark until you answer my specific question, or more clearly explain your point. Thanks.